# How can I position an image at the edge of the screen

Tags: flutter

I have a registration screen in my flutter app and the design I have looks like this:
[image]

The problem I have trying to achieve this design is with aligning the stripes image in the bottom left screen to the edge. I tried to achieve this using the following code.

```
body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    focusNode: _nameNode,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: phoneController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 95),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Register",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0, top: 25),
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/stripes.png",height: 240.0,width:130.0,fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 100),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Have an account already",
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Login here",
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),      
    ],
  ),
```

I have removed some of the widgets but this is what I tried and I got the following result:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoQZZ.jpg)

As you see the stripes image is not starting from the edge of the screen. I also tried to use the `positioned` widget. So I made the `positioned` widget a child of the `stack` widget as follows

```
body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        bottom: -133,
        left: -205,
        height:300.0,
        width:430.0,
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/stripes.png')
      ),
      ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Form(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: nameController,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 95),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Register",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 100),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Have an account already",
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        "Login here",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),      
        ],
      ),
    ]
  ),
```

This aligns the image to the edge of the screen. But since I am using a `Stack` widget it covers other widgets when the page is scrolled. You can check the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a85Ey.jpg). I deleted many widgets to produce minimal code but the main widgets involved are still there. Is there any way to achieve the design? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The layout on the picture is achievable by simple mixture of `column` `row` widgets. Stack is absolute none-sense using here. Purpose of stack widget is stacking widgets on top of each other and not next to each other... Please try to understand that. You already asked similar questions about layout here with the same problem

Comment: @LonelyWolf Yes but my main problem here is reaching the edge of the screen inside the `listview`. I used `stack` just as a try to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

In the padding lines you need to remove const: `padding: EdgeInsets.only (left, top, botom, right)` and try to use Column `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,`
Hope you can leave link on Github

Answer (score 0):

You would need to crop the image before placing it in your app, but you can do it this way:

```
  body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
    Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/stripes.png')),
    ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Form(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 95),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Register",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 100),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Have an account already",
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      "Login here",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ]),
```